# RegEx to validate Number

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, validation

i try to validate a number with a simple scheme but i am not that good in Regular Expressions.

The number has this format:

`XXXXXXX-XX-X` where `X` is a number between `0` and `9`.

I tried the following: `/[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{2]\-[0-9]{1}/` but it does not validate.

Do you see what i have done wrong?

Comment: What language is the RegEx in?

Comment: The RegEx will be used in AS3.

Comment: As a note for the future, the [tag:regex] tag requests adding the language or tool that the regex is to be used in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a typo in your pattern. The third `]` should be a `}`:

```
/[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{1}/
```

You can simplify this further though. You don't need to escape a `-` outside of a character class, and you don't need a quantifier for `{1}`:

```
/[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]/
```

Depending on what regular expression engine you're using, you could probably substitute `\d` for `[0-9]`. In JavaScript they are equivalent, however, in many engines, they are slightly different. `\d` is intended for use with Unicode digits, rather than decimal digits (e.g. it might match [Easter Arabic digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals)). If this is acceptable, you can use:

```
/\d{6}-\d\d-\d/
```

Also, if you need to prohibit any leading or trailing characters, you might consider adding start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors around your pattern:

```
/^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]$/
```

Or

```
/^\d{6}-\d\d-\d$/
```

Comment: Simplify even further with `\d` instead of `[0-9]` (in most languages).

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Thank you very much. Can't believe i didn't saw the typo :( Should stop working for today. Thank you for improving the regex!

Comment: @BrianStephens I've added an alternative pattern and a short description of the differences between `\d` and `[0-9]`.